# SQL query to split concatenated string into separate parts

Tags: ms-access

Need your expertise in one query: I need a SQL query to split concatenated string into separate parts. My data looks like this

```
Name  Location           Name Link   Location Link  Final Location     Material
C50   2398::3276::3916   GA-4-2      58::52::24     558::352::324::70  93530
```

and i want output like this:

```
Name  Location           Name Link   Location Link  Final Location     Material
C50   2398               GA-4-2      58             558                93530
C50   3276               GA-4-2      52             352                93530
C50   3916               GA-4-2      24             324                93530
C50                      GA-4-2                     70                 93530
```

Comment: is the location and last location always 4 and 2 digits respectively?

Comment: @scsimon No, it just a dummy value i mentioned. It can be more than 4 and 2 digits respectively.

Comment: Gosh that "design" is awful. You have multiple of rows of data stuffed into delimited columns. What a nightmare. If this number of elements is fixed this can be wrangled but if it is an unknown number of elements this is going to prove extremely challenging. Hopefully this exercise is part of fixing this schema.

Comment: @SeanLange yea design is very bad and it's quite challenging. Can you please provide your inputs to create a query for this?

Comment: Can you answer this question. Are there ALWAYS three elements or is there an unknown number of elements?

Comment: and respectively, 4 elements in the Final, @ankur_bhardwaj

Comment: @SeanLange  there are always  4 elements in final

Comment: @scsimon there are always 3 elements in location and 4 elements in final location

Comment: And now you are on your own. I provided a working solution for sql server. Now you decide to change the DBMS. Good luck.

Comment: I also removed the sql server tags. Once you decide which DBMS you are using you can add whatever tags are appropriate.

Comment: For Access you would have to use SUBSTRING and nest them to accomplish this.

Comment: @SeanLange substring is an  undefined function in MS access

Comment: I haven't used Access in well over a decade. There is some sort of substring function. A 2 second google search revealed the long forgotten function MID.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a Split function from the internet that includes an IDENTITY column and use the function on each of the concatenated columns to get a table for each of them, and JOIN all the tables on the Identity column.

Comment: Here is one such splitter that would work quite well for this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: @SeanLange is there any solution using direct query? without using function

Comment: @SeanLange is there any query to implement it in MS access?

Comment: @SeanLange I apologies for that. now the requirement has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

As I said before, this design is incredibly painful to work with. Please consider fixing it or you will be forced to continue fighting a losing battle against your database design.

Since you state the number of elements are fixed you can use PARSENAME to split these values. Here is how this might work.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

CREATE TABLE #Something
(
    Name char(3)
    , Location varchar(50)
    , NameLink varchar(10)
    , LocationLink varchar(50)
    , FinalLocation varchar(50)
    , Material int
)

insert #Something
select 'C50'
    , '2398::3276::3916'
    , 'GA-4-2'
    , '58::52::24'
    , '558::352::324::70'
    , 93530

select * from #Something

select Name
    , LEFT(Location, charindex(':', Location, 0) - 1)
    , PARSENAME(replace(Location, '::', '.'), 3)
    , NameLink
    , PARSENAME(replace(LocationLink, '::', '.'), 3)
    , PARSENAME(replace(FinalLocation, '::', '.'), 4)
    , Material
from #Something

UNION ALL

select Name
    , LEFT(Location, charindex(':', Location, 0) - 1)
    , PARSENAME(replace(Location, '::', '.'), 2)
    , NameLink
    , PARSENAME(replace(LocationLink, '::', '.'), 2)
    , PARSENAME(replace(FinalLocation, '::', '.'), 3)
    , Material
from #Something

UNION ALL

select Name
    , LEFT(Location, charindex(':', Location, 0) - 1)
    , PARSENAME(replace(Location, '::', '.'), 1)
    , NameLink
    , PARSENAME(replace(LocationLink, '::', '.'), 1)
    , PARSENAME(replace(FinalLocation, '::', '.'), 2)
    , Material
from #Something

UNION ALL

select Name
    , LEFT(Location, charindex(':', Location, 0) - 1)
    , PARSENAME(replace(Location, '::', '.'), 4)
    , NameLink
    , PARSENAME(replace(LocationLink, '::', '.'), 4)
    , PARSENAME(replace(FinalLocation, '::', '.'), 1)
    , Material
from #Something
```